# MySQL - selecting records without related records with added criteria

Tags: mysql

Recently saw a flurry of posts here and elsewhere about building chat apps, which i assume were for a finals project, and took inspiration from that to try to build by own.

I've got a table of messages sent by user with basically these fields:

```
message_id
chat_id
user_id
message
```

And a table of messages read by user, which has these fields:

```
message_id
chat_id
user_id
date_seen
```

I'm trying to build a query that pulls all messages for a given chat that have not been seen by a particular user. I wasn't having problems pulling unseen messages before I tried to specify the user, but this one is stumping me.

This gives me no results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mc.*
FROM messages_to_chats mc
LEFT JOIN messages_read mr 
ON mc.chat_id = mr.chat_id
WHERE mr.chat_uuid = "1" AND mr.user_id = '1' AND mr.date_seen is null
```

This gives me all messages that haven't been read by anyone:

```
SELECT mc.*
FROM messages_to_chats mc
LEFT JOIN messages_read mr
ON mc.message_id = mr.message_id
WHERE mc.chat_id = "1" AND mr.user_id is null
```

This gives me all messages that HAVE been read by user_id 1:

```
SELECT mc.*
FROM messages_to_chats mc
LEFT JOIN messages_read mr
ON mc.message_id = mr.message_id
WHERE mc.chat_id = "1" AND mr.user_id = '1'
```

When I change the `=` to `!=` in the WHERE clause, it gives me no records at all, rather than just the records from the `mc` table which don't have corresponding records in the `mr` table.

Essentially, there are 4 rows in the messages_to_chats table, which don't have corresponding records in the messages_read table for both that chat_id and that user_id (that message_id may have been read by a different user, however)

Point is when i poll the server through AJAX, the results page (PHP) should only return a JSON encoded list of messages that the logged in user hasn't yet seen.

Anyone have any advice, or need me to provide more info so you can steer me toward the correct solution?

Thanks!

Comment: When using left joins, if you need to limit data on the table on the right side of a left join `FROM A LEFT JOIN B` "B" in this example, you must put the limiting criteria for B on the JOIN itself or the left join in essence is treated as a INNER Join.  so without much additional thought and full reading of your question...  change where to `WHERE mc.chat_id = '1'` and the left join to `LEFT JOIN messages_read mr ON mc.message_id = mr.message_id AND mr.user_ID != '1'`  As to why: two reasons: NULL can't be compared using an = (or !=) and !='1' will eliminate the null values from the left join

Comment: I was actually able to achieve what I hoped for by doing this:

`SELECT message_id, pseudo_user_id, message 
                      FROM   messages_to_chats 
                      WHERE  chat_uuid=? AND message_id NOT IN (
                        SELECT message_id 
                        FROM messages_read 
                        WHERE pseudo_user_id=?`

Comment: At least I think it works - i have two user windows open and they can chat back and forth. Need to create a new chat and make sure the messages don't appear in the wrong places next...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT mc.*
FROM messages_to_chats mc
LEFT JOIN messages_read mr
ON mc.message_id = mr.message_id
WHERE mr.user_id IS NULL and mc.user_id = 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` along with the `mr.user_id IS NULL` will select only the rows in messages_to_chats that have no matching row in messages_read.

Comment: Why the down vote? If you're going to down-vote, at least leave a comment about the reason.

Comment: I don't know why you got a down vote, that actually solved it for me! I'll check it off as correct in a couple minutes, but thank you!

Comment: Thanks Lucas. Glad it worked for you. If you could also mark as accepted, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher I wasn't the one that down-voted, but likely the reason is that you did not "explain why your answer fixes the problem the OP was having". In other words, "teach a man to fish".

Comment: @BA_Webimax: Thanks for the info, it will help me improve my answers going forward.

Comment: Actually @SloanThrasher & @BA_Webimax - that is not the solution. `mc.user_id` is irrelevant - that is who sent the message, i don't care about that - i'm looking for messages for a certain chat which have not been received by a specific user.

Basically, for every message in the MC table, I need to pull out each ID which does not have an entry for the specific user_id in the MR table. Does that make sense at all?

Comment: So change mc.user_id = 1 to mc.chat_id = 1

Comment: It actually appears that:

`SELECT message_id, user_id, message 
                      FROM   messages_to_chats 
                      WHERE  chat_id=? AND message_id NOT IN (
                        SELECT message_id 
                        FROM messages_read 
                        WHERE user_id=?)

Was what I wanted.

Comment: Maybe, but if you end up with a large dataset, it will be slower.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have enough data in there yet to see what could happen.